# How to find HDF5 file groups/keys within Python?

Tags: python, hdf5, pytables, h5py, hdfstore

Lets's say someone gave me a random HDF5 document. I would like to write a function that checks what are the groups/"keys" used.

Take pandas `HDFStore()`. For many methods which retrieve HDF5 data, one requires to know the key, e.g. `pandas.HDFStore.get()`

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.HDFStore.get.html

What is the most efficient way to check the identity of keys if not a priori known?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to use the [h5py](http://www.h5py.org) package:

```
import h5py

with h5py.File("myfile.h5") as f:
    print(f.keys())  # works like a dict
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for this!